# How to convert .jsx into .tsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

This component of the website is in .jsx while whole website is in .tsx. I want to convert this into .tsx file. Can anyone help or guide. No matter what I do, I ran into more and more errors.

```
extend({ RoundedPlaneGeometry: geometry.RoundedPlaneGeometry })

function Scene({ children, ...props }) {
  const ref = useRef()
  const scroll = useScroll()
  const [hovered, hover] = useState(null)
  useFrame((state, delta) => {
    ref.current.rotation.y = -scroll.offset * (Math.PI * 2) // Rotate contents
    state.events.update() // Raycasts every frame rather than on pointer-move
    easing.damp3(state.camera.position, [-state.pointer.x * 2, state.pointer.y * 2 + 4.5, 9], 0.3, delta)
    state.camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0)
  })
  return (
    <group ref={ref} {...props}>
      <Cards category="spring" from={0} len={Math.PI / 4} onPointerOver={hover} onPointerOut={hover} />
      // More Cards
    </group>
  )
}

function Cards({ category, data, from = 0, len = Math.PI * 2, radius = 5.25, onPointerOver, onPointerOut, ...props }) {
  const [hovered, hover] = useState(null)
  const amount = Math.round(len * 22)
  const textPosition = from + (amount / 2 / amount) * len
  return (
    <group {...props}>
      <Billboard position={[Math.sin(textPosition) * radius * 1.4, 0.5, Math.cos(textPosition) * radius * 1.4]}>
        <Text font={suspend(inter).default} fontSize={0.25} anchorX="center" color="black">
          {category}
        </Text>
      </Billboard>
      {Array.from({ length: amount - 3 /* minus 3 images at the end, creates a gap */ }, (_, i) => {
        const angle = from + (i / amount) * len
        return (
          <Card
            key={angle}
            onPointerOver={(e) => (e.stopPropagation(), hover(i), onPointerOver(i))}
            onPointerOut={() => (hover(null), onPointerOut(null))}
            position={[Math.sin(angle) * radius, 0, Math.cos(angle) * radius]}
            rotation={[0, Math.PI / 2 + angle, 0]}
            active={hovered !== null}
            hovered={hovered === i}
            url={`/img${Math.floor(i % 10) + 1}.jpg`}
          />
        )
      })}
    </group>
  )
}

function Card({ url, active, hovered, ...props }) {
  const ref = useRef()
  useFrame((state, delta) => {
    const f = hovered ? 1.4 : active ? 1.25 : 1
    easing.damp3(ref.current.position, [0, hovered ? 0.25 : 0, 0], 0.1, delta)
    easing.damp3(ref.current.scale, [1.618 * f, 1 * f, 1], 0.15, delta)
  })
  return (
    <group {...props}>
      <Image ref={ref} url={url} scale={[1.618, 1, 1]} side={THREE.DoubleSide} />
    </group>
  )
}

function ActiveCard({ hovered, ...props }) {
  const ref = useRef()
  const name = useMemo(() => generate({ exactly: 2 }).join(' '), [hovered])
  useLayoutEffect(() => void (ref.current.material.zoom = 0.8), [hovered])
  useFrame((state, delta) => {
    easing.damp(ref.current.material, 'zoom', 1, 0.5, delta)
    easing.damp(ref.current.material, 'opacity', hovered !== null, 0.3, delta)
  })
  return (
    <Billboard {...props}>
      <Text font={suspend(inter).default} fontSize={0.5} position={[2.15, 3.85, 0]} anchorX="left" color="black">
        {hovered !== null && `${name}\n${hovered}`}
      </Text>
      <Image ref={ref} transparent position={[0, 1.5, 0]} url={`/img${Math.floor(hovered % 10) + 1}.jpg`}>
        <roundedPlaneGeometry parameters={{ width: 3.5, height: 1.618 * 3.5 }} args={[3.5, 1.618 * 3.5, 0.2]} />
      </Image>
    </Billboard>
  )
}
```

I used ChatGPT but it got even worse! For example I don't even know what this error means "Type 'MutableRefObject<Group | undefined>' is not assignable to type 'Ref<Group> | undefined'.
Type 'MutableRefObject<Group | undefined>' is not assignable to type 'RefObject<Group>'.
Types of property 'current' are incompatible.
Type 'Group | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Group | null'.
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Group | null'.ts(2322)"!

Comment: TSX/TS gets transpiled into JSX/JS.  So why worry about converting a JSX to TSX?  Just leave it as JSX.  Otherwise....can you explain what part of TypeScript you do not understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The errors you are getting are related to the typesafeing that TypeScript enforces.

The error you pasted has to do with trying to assign a value of type 'MutableRefObject<Group | undefined>' to something that only accepts type 'Ref | undefined'.

The key difference is:

- Ref: Immutable ref object created by React.createRef()
- MutableRefObject: Created by useRef(), is mutable

If you are trying to ensure/integrate your provided code as a Typescript file you will need to make sure the variable typing/usage is consistent. (That's one of the main reasons for Typescript's existence vs Javascript (which allows for less strict typing, which thus can lead to unexpected errors).

In terms of fixing these errors you'll need to go through the code you provided and modify the type declarations to not use `useRef()` as that makes them `MutableRefObject`'s instead of the desired type of `Ref`. If you want it the other way around you will need to go and change whatever is trying to accept only inputs of type `Ref` so that it accepts the `MutableRefObject` values you are providing.

Hope that helps guide you in the right direction!